# Find max element using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, max

I am new to recursion and the task is to find the POSITION of largest element in the array using recursion. This is my code:

```
def calc(low , high):
    print(low, high)
    if low == high:
        return low
    max_1 = calc(low , low +high//2)
    max_2 = calc(low + high//2 , high)
    if a[max_1] > a[max_2]:
        return max_1
        
a = [4,3,6,1,9]
print(calc(0 , len(a)))
```

What am I doing wrong?
While google gives me solutions for finding the max element in array none of them have solutions for finding position of max element. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are doing binary search in an unsorted array and you compute the middle point wrong. You need to use a linear search.

Comment: @fafl i am tryna use divide and conquer to solve this problem. So I dont think it matters if the array is sorted or not.

Comment: `low + high//2` is not the middle element, you're missing parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Still doesnt work lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Two tiny mistakes are:

- Base case should be `low + 1 == high`
- Mid point should be `(low + high) // 2`

```
def calc(low , high):
    if low + 1 == high:
        return low 
    max_1 = calc(low , (low + high) // 2)
    max_2 = calc((low + high) // 2 , high)
    if a[max_1] > a[max_2]:
        return max_1
    else:
        return max_2
        
a = [4,3,6,1,9]

print(calc(0 , len(a)))
## 4
```

Your solution generates infinite recursion due to the wrong base case and the mid-point.

When `low == 0` and `high == 1`, since `low != high` you trigger two calls

```
max_1 = calc(low , low + high // 2) 
max_2 = calc(low + high // 2 , high)
```

which are evaluated to

```
max_1 = calc(0, 0) ## This got returned to 0, because low == high
max_2 = calc(0, 1) ## Notice here again low == 0 and high == 1
```

The second call `max_2 = calc(0, 1)` triggers again another two calls one of which is again `max_2 = calc(0, 1)`. This triggers infinite recursions that never returns back to `max_2` and `max_2` will never get evaluated and thus neither the lines after it (`if a[max_1] > a[max_2]: ...` ).

That is why you should check for base case `low + 1 == high` instead of `low == high`. Now you could test yourself and guess if the following code will generate infinite recursion or not. Will this time `max_2` gets returned value assigned to it and the lines after it get evaluated?

```
def calc(low , high):
    if low + 1 == high: # Here is changed from your solution
        return low 
    max_1 = calc(low , low + high // 2) # Here is same to your solution
    max_2 = calc(low + high // 2 , high) # Here is same as well
    if a[max_1] > a[max_2]:
        return max_1
    else:
        return max_2
```

If you get the answer right, you are half way in understanding your mistake. Then you can play with different mid-point and print at each level of recursion to see how that affects results and get a full understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do. You should pass list slices to the function - this makes it much simpler than trying to pass low and high indices, and avoids accessing the list as a global variable - and add the midpoint to the resulting index that comes from the right hand side of the list.

```
def idxmax(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return 0
    midpoint = len(l) // 2
    a = idxmax(l[:midpoint])
    b = idxmax(l[midpoint:]) + midpoint
    if l[a] >= l[b]:
        return a
    else:
        return b

print(idxmax([4,3,6,1,9]))
```

This returns the index of the *first* occurrence of the maximum, e.g. `idxmax([4,9,3,6,1,9]) == 1`

If you want to implement it by passing indices instead of slices (possibly more efficient by not making multiple copies of the list), you could do it like this:

```
def idxmax(l, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(l) - 1
    if end == start:
        return start
    midpoint = (start + end) // 2
    a = idxmax(l, start, midpoint)
    b = idxmax(l, midpoint + 1, end)
    if l[a] >= l[b]:
        return a
    else:
        return b

print(idxmax([4,3,6,1,9]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Any idea why my solution is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the task was to find the **POSITION of the max number** only (and not the value itself).

So, the function starts by comparing the last value with the max value of the list and returns the length of the list (minus one) as position if True. then it is recursively called to a shorter list and compared again until it left with only one value in the list

```
def calc(lst):
    if lst[len(lst) - 1] == max(lst):
        return len(lst) - 1
    if len(lst) > 1:
        return calc(lst[:-1])


print(calc([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))  # 6
print(calc([7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))  # 0
print(calc([0, 1, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6]))  # 2
```

Comment: Using the `max` function is a bit like cheating here, you could just write `return max(range(len(lst)), key=lambda x: lst[x])`

Comment: @fafl I was following the task as described, to find the position of the max value (not the value) using a recursive function